# Is it okay to ask the notice period of future employer

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I have a new Job offer and I don't know the notice period of the new compnany, Is it okay to ask the notice period of future employer

Comment: Uh. What is the point of doing that ?

Comment: @GautierC - Would you want to commit yourself to a 4 month notice period unknowingly?

Comment: @MartinSmith read the contract before signing it ?

Comment: It might be wise to be less specific, and ask the open question in which areas your contract will differ from applicable defaults. (It might also be good to first ask _which_ default rules apply. Not only can there be legal defaults, the might also be collective bargaining defaults, industry-wide defaults etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always ask. But asking this question will make the interviewer worry about how serious you are about this job application.

Personally, I would not ask. Instead, I would get the job offer, accept it in principle, then review the *entire* employment contract before signing it. It is entirely legitimate to ask that something unacceptable in a contract be changed, and to walk away without signing if an agreement can not be reached. Of course that would mean walking away from the job too.

Before you do anything else, though, I suggest researching this in other ways. Find out whether there is a commonly agreed upon notice period in that country -- or if one is officially required at all, rather than just being a courtesy. See if you can find the answer for this company on line somewhere, or find a way to ask anonymously. If you can get the answer without having to ask directly, that's less likely to cause problems.

Comment: Would do the same here. But I would **never** ever ask it during an interview, I don't even see the point to do it anyway.

Comment: In some countries, notice periods can be unreasonably long. (See past questions about changing jobs in India, for example.) If there is reason to suspect that kind of policy, it's worth researching. In the US, where employment at will is the standard, this issue generally doesn't arise.

Comment: ok I understand a bit better now. But what is the point to ask it during an interview. Checking it during the last step of the recruitment process is better, isn't it ?

Comment: That's what I said: better to check it earlier or later, unless there is some reason you expect it to be a problem and have a good reason for discussing it with them.

Comment: @keshlam: As long as the notice period is the same for employer and employee, it protects each side. And your _next_ employer is aware that everyone has long notice periods, so they are absolutely fine waiting for your notice period to finish. As an employer who is being laid off and the notice period started running, it may give you an advantage since you can start earlier at a new job.

Comment: Good advice. Check that (along with the other details) when you get the contract. Query anything you're not happy with *after* they've offered you the job.

Comment: @gnasher: Debatable. I consider a notice period of 3 months abusive, but apparently there are places where that's common.

Comment: @keshlam Other cultures would consider a job security of 0 (fire-at-will) abusive. I guess it depends on the culture you got thrown into as "the norm".

Comment: If there is no notice specified in the contract, defer to local laws and what you find reasonable. For example, if no notice is legally required, you still might consider it reasonable to give some notice, unless there are extreme circumstances that prevent this.

Comment: @keshlam: It protects you as well. If your employer decides to fire you, you will get paid for three months from the moment he tells you. And if you look for new employment while employed, your next employer _knows_ that you have long notice period, because everyone has.

Answer (score 4):

Thats not a good idea. It will cause the recruiter to think that you're already planning to leave this new company soon should you get the job, which is not a good impression to give.

Notice periods are usually outlined in the contract. So before signing it, you should read it. If there is no notice period specified in the contract, the legal standard in your country applies. So, for better or worse, you'll get this information when you get the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than asking specifically about the notice period, you should ask to see the contract and examine it for yourself.

Say something like "I appreciate the job offer.  Before accepting I would like a chance to review the full contract.  Can you please send me a copy?"  If I were the hiring manager I wouldn't find this strange or off putting.

If there is no contract clause regarding this then refer to local employment law as to what is required of the employee by default.