# Ask politely for the contract

Tags: new-job, job-change, india, notice-period

I got an offer from a company. They asked me to sign the offer as acceptance and send it in 24 hours. It had the compensation, role, probation period and the evaluation process after probation. I signed it and sent them back. But there wasn't any mention on the notice period of the company in the offer. As I thought it will be less positive to ask about the notice period as per [Is it okay to ask the notice period of future employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69399/is-it-okay-to-ask-the-notice-period-of-future-employer) I was waiting to read employment contract. The offer noted that all other details will be included in the employment contract.

Hence I asked them for the contract and salary split up. They sent me the salary split up. But I haven't received my contract details yet. When I checked back with the concerned person the reply was that I will get my employment contract when I join the company as discussed and hence will sign it on the joining date. But I don't remember having the discussion. I am a little concerned that I might end up with a higher notice period but the person says that I will get the contract on the joining date and I don't want to risk anything on the last minute. Also I don't want to make the employer to have a negative impression on the offered role by asking it directly. I am already serving my notice period with my current employer. How should I proceed further on this?

Comment: Where in the world are you? Where I live, this is totally unheard of. You receive a contract with the full details that you sign (or reject). Nothing is signed before that as it's legally invalid to accept something you don't even know yet. You sign the full contract before even giving notice to your old job. However, this may be totally different wherever you live.

Comment: @nvoigt I am from India. Its not common here too. Its just that the offer letter had an outline of the conditions like salary, probation etc. They said they will send the contract once I sign offer. I haven't signed the contract. I just accepted the offer. As you said it might differ by geography.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're being scammed.  If they are waiting until the last possible date to give you the contract, that's designed to deliberately limit your options and create pressure on you to sign whatever they give you.  The contract will have something in it not in your favor, and that's why they're stalling.

Ask once more for a written contract with all the details, immediately.  It's not hard for any legitimate business to generate one, and don't accept, "our hr/legal dept is working on it".  If you encounter any resistance, don't play the game - find something else!

Comment: My thought process was also along similar lines as your answer. Thanks I have mailed them back for the same.

Comment: They know that you have the notice-period concern.  I see so many people from India post here where the employer is abusing the notice-period situation.  Is that the law there, with notice-periods, or just tradition?  Whatever it is, it sucks!

Comment: Ya. My current company had service bond of 2 yrs. So I have to work with them mandatory for 2 yrs n have to pay 3 months gross pay if I need to leave. I am severly underpaid too. So I just completed 2 years n leaving the company. Sadly most service companies work like this. Its a cultural thing here. Many people take up the job as they don't want to be unemployed after college. Big service companies are hit by major amount of attrition.

Comment: Hmm.  See here.  https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-legal-issues-for-leaving-a-company-while-under-a-signed-bond